# Update multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to do something like this

```
Update Tenancy
set Text5 = ('55', '57', '89')
where PK in ('1', '2', '3')
```

I'm doing this with 1000 PKs, so just looking for a fast and safe way.

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
pk      text5
--------------
1       55
2       57
3       89
```

Comment: is there a relation between the PK value and the values of text5?

Comment: Create a mapping table with pk/newvalue. UPDATE JOIN.

Comment: Where is the data for the update coming from? If possible, sticking it in a temp table against the PK, and then joining to it and updating it is one way to tackle it.

Comment: Yeah i can do a temp table but im just seeing if there is a faster way as i have to do this every week with 1000 records

Comment: @JD_123 so where are you getting the 1000's of records from? Are they in another SQL table? Excel? printed on paper? And by `faster` are you talking in terms of your time, or performance of the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a table value constructor like this :

```
WITH 
T AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1', '55'),
                            ('2', '57'),
                            ('3', '89')
                    ) AS TBL (pk, text5)
      ) 
UPDATE TNC
SET    Text5 = T.text5
FROM   Tenancy AS TNC
       JOIN T ON TNC.PK = T.PK;
```

Beware… this constructor is limited to exactly 1000 tuples !

Comment: The 1,000 limit is only when used in `INSERT ... VALUES`

Comment: im doing it this way for the 1000 records but i having issues when i add Begin trans where would be the best place to put it

Comment: You need a semicolon before `WITH` and then contain the whole thing in a transaction

Answer (score 0):

A CASE Expression will work for you:

```
Update Tenancy
set Text5 = CASE WHEN PK = '1' THEN '55' WHEN PK = '2' THEN '57' WHEN PK = '3' THEN '89' END
where PK in ('1','2','3')
```

This will get tedious though, so a table holding this relationship between `pk` and `text5` would be a better solution in the end.

Comment: The "Simple" form of the `CASE` expression can save the need to repeat `PK =` every time (`CASE PK WHEN '1' THEN '55' WHEN '2' THEN '57' WHEN  '3' THEN '89' END`

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `text5` with `values` constructor :

```
update t 
     set t.text5 = tt.text5
from Tenancy t cross apply
     ( values (1, 55), (2, 57), (3, 89) 
     ) tt(pk, text5)
where tt.pk = t.pk;
```

Comment: Why not just use `join`?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is creating a temp table, to join to:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    [Id] INT,
    [Text5] INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT 1,55 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,57 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,89;

UPDATE T
SET T.Text5 = TT.Text5
FROM Tenancy AS T
INNER JOIN #TempTable AS TT ON T.[PK] = TT.[Id];

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

One advantage of this is, if the data is in Excel (or similar) you can use a formula to create your `SELECT` statements to populate the temp table. You can also index the temp table, should it require it.